# Using Cake PHP's find method to limit the number of records in a particular model

Tags: cakephp

I have the following find function:

```
$this->MyModel->find('all', array('conditions' => array('id' => $id)));
```

which returns an array of this form

```
Array
(
    [Model1] => Array
        (
            [Model1] => Array
                (
                    ...
                    ...
                )
        )
    [Model2] => Array
       (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    ...
                    ...
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    ...
                    ...
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    ...
                    ...
                )
            ...
            ...
            ...

            )
)
```

How do I alter the the `find` all to limit how many elements the second model are fetched (`Model2`)?

I can add `conditions => array( 'limit' => 10 )` but that limits the number of elements of the outer array - not Model2 i.e. the second nested array!

Any ideas?  Thank you :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use cake's [containable](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1323/Containable) behaviour here to limiting the records of your second model. Here's what you can do using containable to achieve this.

```
    $this->Model->contain = array('Model2' => array('limit' => 10));
    $this->Model->find('all', array('conditions' => $conditions));
```

Now you will get maximum of 10 records from Model2.

Comment: Is it possible to give page number (offset) for this ?

Answer (score 1):

If this is something that you want to do each time you do a find('all'), you can use the 'limit' parameters in the associations arrays in the model:

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'OtherModel' => array(
        'className' => 'OtherModel',
        'foreignKey' => 'model_id',
        'limit' => 10
    )
```

Alternatively, you could also modify this value just before calling the find() method:

```
$this->MyModel->hasMany['OtherModel']['limit'] = 10;
$this->MyModel->find('all', array('conditions' => array('id' => $id)));
```